# Copy arrows from conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a way to copy the arrows of the conditional formatting icon set. I want the arrows to be static when copied because the data should be linked to a Word document. The conditional formatting is lost when putting the data into word. There is no need for the data that is next to it. Is there a possibility to either copy the arrows or create the exact same arrows via VBA? Or is it possible to check what kind of arrow the cell contains and replace it with an ASCII arrow?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFTXE.png)

Comment: It's simple Copy Column from Excel you have applied CF with arrow, reach to Word,, click `Paste` & `Paste Special`,,, and you may select any of the options,, `Microsoft Excel Code Object`,, or `Bitmap`  or `Picture (Enhance Metafile)` ,, you get data along with Arrow !! Better pick as Excel Object. You can't get CF if use Paste Link!!